# Authenticate user / group created with AWS Identity Center (not IAM)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-devops

We have created a user with AWS identity center (not IAM). What we want is to authenticate this created user to excecute or trigger an API. In simpler words only those users which has been created with AWS identity center and Are present in particular group those can access that particular API.